# Microsoft bot framework message edit event

Tags: node.js, botframework, slack

In Microsoft bot framework, using node.js sdk, is it possible to listen to message edit events? For example in slack users can edit their previously sent messages, is there a way to listen to that edit event from the bots side?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the BotFramework does not forward message edits to Bots.  This has been noted and added to the backlog.

Comment: Four years later, is there any update on this or a GitHub issue where we can track the progress?